# Получить ссылки на изображения из строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пишу парсер изоображнений с Мангачан.ру

Как разобрать этот код, что бы получить ссылки на изоображения:

```
"fullimg":["http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/001.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/002.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/003.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/004.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/005.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/006.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/007.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/008.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/009.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/010.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/011.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/012.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/013.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/014.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/015.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/016.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/017.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/018.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/019.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/020.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/021.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/022.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/023.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/024.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/025.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/026.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/027.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/028.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/029.webp","http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/030.webp","http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/031.webp",]
```

Мой код работает, но возвращает пустоту:

```
 @Override
public List<Image> getChapterImageLinks(Chapter chapter) throws Exception {
    List<Image> images = new LinkedList<>();

    String referrer = url + chapter.getLink()+"#page=1";
    Document doc = JsoupHelper.getHTMLPage(referrer);

    Elements scripts = doc.select("script");

    for (Element script : scripts) {
        String scriptText = script.html();

        if (scriptText.contains("\"fullimg\"")) {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(scriptText)) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    if (line.contains("\"fullimg\"")) {
                        String link = line.split("fullimg:[\"")[1]
                        .split(",]")[0];

                        String extension = link.substring(
                                link.length() - 3, link.length());

                        images.add(new Image(link ,
                                referrer, extension));
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return images;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать jackson

```
public class JsonParserTest {

    private String s = "\"fullimg\":[\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/001.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/002.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/003.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/004.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/005.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/006.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/007.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/008.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/009.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/010.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/011.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/012.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/013.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/014.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/015.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/016.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/017.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/018.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/019.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/020.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/021.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/022.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/023.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/024.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/025.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/026.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/027.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/028.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/029.webp\",\"http://im2.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/030.webp\",\"http://im.mangachan.ru/manganew_webp/-9new/-/1438449948_-okazaki-mari_v5_ch23/031.webp\",]";

    @Test
    public void fullImgTest() throws IOException {
        s = s.replace("\"fullimg\":",""); //Оставляем только массив
        s = s.replace(",]","]"); //Если в конце пустой элемент уберем его
        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        //Получаем список строк
        List<String> ia = m.readValue(s,new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
        for (String i : ia) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой regexp использовать:

```
(http://)(([0-9a-zA-Z._-])+(/))+([0-9])+(\.webp)
```